# How to prepare a blank website to be dockerized?

Tags: docker

I have a totally empty debian9 on which I installed docker-ce and nothing else.

My client wants me to run a website (already done locally on my PC) that he can **migrate/move rapidly from one server to another moving docker images**.

My idea is to install **some empty docker image**, and then install on it manually all dependencies (ngingrtmp, apache2, nodejs, mysql, phpmyadmin, php, etc...)

**I need to install all these dependencies MANUALLY** (to keep control)  - not using a ready to go docker images from dockerhub, and then to create an IMAGE of ALL things I have done (including these dependencies, but also files I will upload).

Problem is : I have no idea how to start a blank image, connect to it and then save a modified image with components and dependencies I will run.

I am aware that the SIZE may be bigger with a simple dockerfile, but I need to customize lots of things such as using php5.6, apache2.2, edit some php.ini etc etc..

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to define you're dependencies on the docker file then you can have an approach like this, spin up a linux container with a base image and go inside the docker

```
sudo docker exec -it <Container ID> /bin/bash
```

install your dependencies as you install on any other linux server.

```
sudo apt-get install -y ngingrtmp apache2 nodejs mysql phpmyadmin php
```

then exit the container by ctrl+p and ctrl+q and now commit the changes you made

```
sudo docker commit CONTAINER_ID new-image-name
```

run `docker images` command and you will see the new image you have created, then you can use/move that image

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a Dockerfile with the following content

```
FROM SCRATCH
```

But then you will need to build and add the operating system yourself.

For instance, alpine linux does this in the following way:

```
FROM scratch
ADD rootfs.tar.xz /
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

Where rootfs.tar.xz is a file of less of 2MB available on alpine's github repository (version 3.7 for x86_64 arch):

https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/tree/61c3181ad3127c5bedd098271ac05f49119c9915/versions/library-3.7/x86_64

Or you can begin with alpine itself, but you said that you don't want to depend on ready to go docker images.

A good start point for you (if you decide to use alpnie linux), could look like the one available at https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/eaf4c70fb21f167f77e0c9d4b6f8b8635b1cb4b6/2.4/alpine/Dockerfile

As you can see, A Dockerfile can became very big and complex because within it you provision all the software you need for running your image.

Once you have your Dockerfile, you can build the image with:

```
docker build .
```

You can give it a name:

```
docker build -t mycompany/myimage:1.0
```

Then you can run your image with:

```
docker run mycompany/myimage:1.0
```

Hope this helps.